# How to define font-face for multiple typefaces inside a single font file?

Tags: css, font-face

I have a font family in a single font file with multipe weights & styles (Regular, Bold, Italic, Bold Italic) and would like to define the font faces using @font-face tag. How can I do that?

If I do this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Font Regular';
    src: url('font.eot');
    src: url('font.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('font.woff') format('woff'),
       url('font.ttf') format('truetype');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
font-family: 'Font Bold';
    src: url('font.eot');
    src: url('font.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('font.woff') format('woff'),
        url('font.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

... it shows both Regular and Bold in regular typeface.

If I set font-weight: bold for h1, h2, h3 etc., it shows these elements as electronic bold. How can I extract multiple typefaces from a single font file?

Answer (score 3):

If you do in fact have all the weights and styles embedded into a *single* font file, then I believe your only solution is to separate those definitions into multiple files (not sure what all would be involved in that), as to my knowledge `@font-face` can only deal with them as separate files.

Normally, font families that are open and available to be used on the web have the weights and styles broken into *separate* files, not included in one *single* file. You might search to be sure your font is not available already as separate files. All the examples I am aware of always have them as separate files. That way, a different file can be used for the various weights/styles, but the same `font-family` name used, like so:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'myFont';
    src: url('font-REGULAR.eot');
    src: url('font-REGULAR.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('font-REGULAR.woff') format('woff'),
       url('font-REGULAR.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'myFont';
    src: url('font-BOLD.eot');
    src: url('font-BOLD.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('font-BOLD.woff') format('woff'),
        url('font-BOLD.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'myFont';
    src: url('font-ITALIC.eot');
    src: url('font-ITALIC.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('font-ITALIC.woff') format('woff'),
       url('font-ITALIC.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: italic;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'myFont';
    src: url('font-BOLDITALIC.eot');
    src: url('font-BOLDITALIC.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('font-BOLDITALIC.woff') format('woff'),
        url('font-BOLDITALIC.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With this simple tool, you can split up a single font file into multiple files. Works on both Mac and Windows.

http://peter.upfold.org.uk/projects/dfontsplitter

Hope that helps